# htmlspecialchars set double_encode false as default

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I have a huge system and for security reasons I want to do `htmlspecialchars` on all `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables. the problem is that there will be duplicate `htmlspecialchars` and instead `<script>` it will show

```
&lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

Is there any way to set double_encode false as default instead true?

Comment: Since PHP 5.2.3, parameter double_encode was added. More info:
http://php.net/manual/ro/function.htmlspecialchars.php
You can simply add false for double_encode parameter to your htmlspecialchars function.

Comment: I know.. my question is if I can do this globally to all htmlspecialchars functions because I have a lot of them..

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the function and set `double_encode` parameter to false as default.
Here is the example code:

```
<?php
rename_function('htmlspecialchars', 'renamed_htmlspecialchars');
function overriden_htmlspecialchars($string, $flags=NULL, $encoding='cp1251', $double_encode=false) {
    $flags = $flags ? $flags : (ENT_COMPAT|ENT_HTML401);
    return renamed_htmlspecialchars($string, $flags, $encoding, $double_encode);
}
override_function('htmlspecialchars', '$string, $flags, $encoding, $double_encode', 'return overriden_htmlspecialchars($string, $flags, $encoding, $double_encode);');
?>
```

Comment: I tried it but it requires PECL apd. There is no way without any plugins?